# java regex split string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm kind of stuck trying to come up with regular expression to break up strings with the following properties:

1. Delimited by the | (pipe) character
2. If an individual value contains a pipe, escaped with \ (backslash)
3. If an individual value ends with backslash, escaped with backslash

So for example, here are some strings that I want to break up:

1. `One|Two|Three` should yield: `["One", "Two", "Three"]`
2. `One\|Two\|Three` should yield: `["One|Two|Three"]`
3. `One\\|Two\|Three` should yield: `["One\", "Two|Three"]`

Now how could I split this up with a single regex?

UPDATE: As many of you already suggested, this is not a good application of regex. Also, the regex solution is orders of magnitude slower than just iterating over the characters. I ended up iterating over the characters:

```
public static List<String> splitValues(String val) {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean esc = false;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    final CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(val);
    for(char c = it.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = it.next()) {
        if(esc) {
            sb.append(c);
            esc = false;
        } else if(c == '\\') {
            esc = true;
        } else if(c == '|') {
            list.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    if(sb.length() > 0) {
        list.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Let's make it clear. What you want is this: split by | and remove it from the string, don't split by \| and remove \ from the string and finally split by \\| and remove \| from the first part and \ from the second part. How do you think this could be made with one regexp? It seems like completely different situations to me...

Comment: Is it possible to change your delimiters?

Comment: I think you guys are right! This might be too much for regex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is not to use the `split()` method.  That forces you to use a lookbehind to detect escaped characters, but that fails when the escapes are themselves escaped (as you've discovered).  You need to use `find()` instead, to match the *tokens* instead of the delimiters:

```
public static List<String> splitIt(String source)
{
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^|\\\\]|\\\\.)+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (m.find())
  {
    result.add(m.group().replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1"));
  }
  return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  String[] test = { "One|Two|Three", 
                    "One\\|Two\\|Three", 
                    "One\\\\|Two\\|Three", 
                    "One\\\\\\|Two" };
  for (String s :test)
  {
    System.out.printf("%n%s%n%s%n", s, splitIt(s));
  }
}
```

output:

```
One|Two|Three
[One, Two, Three]

One\|Two\|Three
[One|Two|Three]

One\\|Two\|Three
[One\, Two|Three]

One\\\|Two
[One\|Two]
```

Comment: That's impressive.  Could you explain how the pattern works?  I still struggle with regular expressions.

Comment: This works like a charm!! Thanks again @Alan Moore!! Now how would you do the reverse?

Comment: @Paul: The basic idea is that you never match a backslash without consuming the next character, too.  That way you'll never get out of sync with the escape sequences.  But if you really want to grok regexes, you should read [The Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC&dq=isbn:0596528124&ei=p14zTuOEDI3elQS495j1Aw).